# How to create DataTemplate with ItemsControl from code behind WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

I have a custom ListView with some constant GridViewColumns, that I create in XAML like this

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="150">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfSubObjects}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubObjectName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

ItemSource for the ListView itself is a list of objects that themselve contain a list of subobjects (ListOfSubObjects) to properties of which I want to bind the displayed text.

I want to dynamically add GridViewColumns with the same structure from code behind, but I can't find a way to add ItemTemplate with ItemSource to DataTemplate. How can I do it?

Comment: You may declare DataTemplates as resources and retrieve them by FindResource.

Comment: Search for questions "wpf gridview dynamic columns". This is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Sinatr, I know that I can create simple column with `var gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn() { Header = header, DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(subObject.property) };` and then add it to my ListView, what i can't find is how do I create a column that matches my template.

Comment: @Clemens The problem with DataTemplate as a resource is that I need to change the binding of the TextBlock e.g. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ThisPropertyChanges}"/>` and not the DataContext, is there a way to do that in this case?

Comment: @AlexLikeDark: Not in XAML, but if you create the template programmatically, you could simply replace the binding path in the `string` that you pass to `XamlReader.Parse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `XamlReader.Parse` method to create an elements from a XAML string dynamically:

```
const string Xaml = "<ItemsControl ItemsSource=\"{Binding ListOfSubObjects}\">" +
"                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>" +
"                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>" +
"                        <StackPanel Orientation=\"Vertical\"></StackPanel>" +
"                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>" +
"                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>" +
"                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>" +
"                    <DataTemplate>" +
"                        <TextBlock Text=\"{Binding SubObjectName}\"/>" +
"                    </DataTemplate>" +
"                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>" +
"            </ItemsControl>";

ParserContext parserContext = new ParserContext();
parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");

ItemsControl itemsControl = XamlReader.Parse(Xaml, parserContext) as ItemsControl;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to load the entire GridViewColumn this way, worked perfectly. Also i found out that this is a recomended way of creating elements [MSDOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 1):

You can use FrameworkElementFactory to add datatemplate to celltemplate and also this example apply to add DataTemplate into ItemTemplate:

```cs
GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
FrameworkElementFactory fc = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ItemsControl));
fc.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("ListOfSubObject"));
dt.VisualTree = fc;
gvc.CellTemplate = dt;
```